# how can i get a random sample from dataframe but have it contain a distribution of a variable? PYTHON

Tags: python

context:
i have a large dataframe that looks similar to this but has 200k rows

| name | country | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| neymar | brazil | 1234 |
| ronaldo | portugal | 5678 |
| benzema | france | 9012 |
| t. silva | brazil | 3456 |

i want to take a random sample of 100 from this dataframe but ensure i have a few from each country in the random sample - how could i do this? thanks in advance!!

`df.sample(100, random_state = 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the distribution by country you could use `sklearn.utils.resample` setting `stratify=df.country`.

For example:

```py
from sklearn.utils import resample

resample(df, n_samples=500, replace=False, stratify=df.country, random_state=123)
```

More details in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html